How to form an AP which contains common terms of two other APs?
I got this question when I was going through a question from the infamous entrance exam JEE. It was a question from the JEE Advanced 2018, Paper 1.
The question is as follows:
Let X be the set consisting of the first 2018 terms of the arithmetic progression 1,6,11,...., and Y be the set consisting of the first 2018 terms of the arithmetic progression 9,16,23...... Then, the number of elements in the set X∪ Y is _______?
Note: The above question is not the question I want to answer for.
The answer to this question is easy to get online and the method they use is, to find n(X∩Y) to complete the equation n(X∪Y)=n(X)+n(Y)−n(X∩Y).
The method to find n(X∩Y) is pretty straightforward, but the problem arose when I tried to form a new AP out of the common terms of two APs. This is how I approached the problem:
Let,
$t_1=a_1+(n-1)d_1$
$t_2=a_2+(n-1)d_2$
then, the AP looks as follows:
$a_1,a_1+d_1,a_1+2d_1,....$
$a_2,a_2+d_2,a_2+2d_2,....$
Let, the first common terms be:
$a_1+(\alpha -1)d_1=a_2+(\beta -1)d_2$
Then the common terms of the AP should repeat over a constant interval, which leads to the Framework of AP we need. Which should look like so; (Where the assumed interval of repetition of the first AP is "x" and the second AP is "y")
$t'= a_1 + (\alpha +nx-1)d_1$
(or)
$t'= a_2 + (\beta +ny-1)d_2$
Now the problem is We need to know the second common term to determine the "x" and "y" value. But I require a method such that it gives out the form of AP just by giving the form of $t_1$ and $t_2$
I have laid the foundation for the problem like so, Now the problem is I don't know how to proceed. And I am not sure if my statements are correct too. So I would like to have the solution to my question, as well as, my method to be verified.

I think the key is to figure out what is the common difference of the AP you get when intersecting two other APs. I recommend trying several numerical examples—just pick a few at random, with common differences between $2$ and $9$ say. You should be able to formulate a belief about the common difference of the intersection, and that will help you prove what you want to prove.

The common difference for the new arithmetic progression will be the least common multiple of the common differences of the two parent arithmetic progressions.
$$d_3 = \mathrm{lcm}\left(d_1,d_2\right)$$
Now it remains to find the first term of the new arithmetic progression. This first term is exactly $$a_3 =a_1+d_1k$$ where $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $$a_1+d_1k \equiv a_2 \pmod{d_2}$$
Note that this $k$ may not exist, in the case that $\gcd(d_1,d_2) > 1$ and $a_1 \not\equiv a_2 \pmod{\gcd(d_1,d_2)}$.
For example, the sequences 1, 3, 5, 7, ... and 2, 4, 6, 8, ... have no overlap. In other cases, $k$ must exist and can be found using the division algorithm.
For the problem that inspired your question, this method yields $k=3$ as we have $1+3\cdot 5 \equiv 9 \pmod{7}$. Therefore the first term is $a_3=16$. The common difference is $d_3 = \mathrm{lcm}\left(5,7\right)=35$.

But is there any other algebraic way to solve this? I mean, without using LCMs and GCDs. For example, I give you two APs like $t_1=n$ and $t_2=kn$ then I should be able to solve for the new AP without knowing what is k.

@DavidK Understood. I am new to this platform, moreover, I am a high schooler. So yeah I am a rookie. Thanks for educating me.

And also can I get the proof for this method? So I can get to the bottom of it and understand it better.
